# result output disappears too quickly

Tags: javascript, html

the correct or wrong answer outputs and quickly disappears. How do I get the answer to remain on the screen. I want to keep the html and js files separate. What I want to do later is add other phrases to the program.

INDEX.HTML

```
<head> </head> 
<body>  
    <form  name="myForm">
        <div id ="phrase"></div>    
        <input type = "text" id = "textinput"> 
        <button id="myBtn">Click here</button>
        <div id ="feedback"></div>
    </form>
    <script src = "phraseScrambler.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

PHRASESCRAMBLER.JS

```
var words = ['how', 'are', 'you', 'today?'];
var correctInput = "how are you today";
var userInput = 'how are you today?';
var newWords = words.slice(0); 
shuffle(newWords); 
question();

function question() {
    var el = document.getElementById('phrase');
    el.textContent = newWords.join(' '); 
    document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = checkAnswer;}

function checkAnswer() {
    var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');
    if (document.myForm.textinput.value == correctInput) {
        elMsg.textContent= "correct";}
    else {
        elMsg.textContent= "wrong answer";}}

function shuffle(newWords) {
    var counter = newWords.length, temp, index;
    while (counter > 0) {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
    counter--;
    temp = newWords[counter];
    newWords[counter] = newWords[index];
    newWords[index] = temp;}
    return newWords;}
```

Comment: Your button is submitting your form on click. Prevent its default behavior or use `<button type="button">` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't bind click event if you want to handle form submission, forms have dedicated event called `onsubmit`. When form is submitted default browser behavior is to navigate to form action (in your case reload the page). You need to prevent this by returning false from the `onsubmit` handler.

Corrected HTML will be (I gave an id to the form):

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm"> ... </form>
```

And then event handling will look like (note `return false;` in `checkAnswer` function):

```js
var words = ['how', 'are', 'you', 'today?'];
var correctInput = "how are you today";
var userInput = 'how are you today?';
var newWords = words.slice(0);
shuffle(newWords);
question();

function question() {
    var el = document.getElementById('phrase');
    el.textContent = newWords.join(' ');
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = checkAnswer;
}

function checkAnswer() {
    var elMsg = document.getElementById('feedback');
    if (document.myForm.textinput.value == correctInput) {
        elMsg.textContent = "correct";
    } else {
        elMsg.textContent = "wrong answer";
    }
    return false;
}

function shuffle(newWords) {
    var counter = newWords.length,
        temp, index;
    while (counter > 0) {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        counter--;
        temp = newWords[counter];
        newWords[counter] = newWords[index];
        newWords[index] = temp;
    }
    return newWords;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <div id ="phrase"></div>    
    <input type = "text" id = "textinput" /> 
    <button>Click here</button>
    <div id ="feedback"></div>
</form>
```